# CMIS add custom type to cm:folder

Tags: alfresco, cmis, chemistry

I've one repository where I create some Site for store all documents and folders that my organization create.
I've one web app that include this php library https://github.com/dkd/php-cmis-client (port of Apache Chemistry Java implementation).
So I can creates documents, folder, set some properties, etc... but I would like to do "more".

I would like to extend the model and create my own model. In this case, It's very simple, I create "myPersonal" model, and create one custom type 'folderAmp' (his parents is cm:folder). And I extend this custom type and create a new property "myP:idNew" where I want to store some id code.

So, When I create a folder with this library (or maybe in java) I create it with...

JAVA

```
Folder parent = ....
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "a new folder");
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");

// create the folder
Folder newFolder = parent.createFolder(properties);
```

PHP

```
$properties = array(
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::OBJECT_TYPE_ID => 'cmis:folder',
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::NAME => 'Demo Folder'
);

try {
    $folder = $session->createFolder(
        $properties,
        $session->createObjectId($session->getRepositoryInfo()->getRootFolderId())
    );
```

So if I want to add my new custom type... What I've to do?

I try to add with this:

properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder, **myP:folderAmp"** but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [createType()](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/types/index.html#creating-updating-and-deleting-types). Not all repositories support it.

Get the CMIS Workbench from https://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html , login into your repository, and open the "Types window". Select the folder type (`cmis:folder`). If the "Create Type" button on the top is enabled you can create a new subtype of `cmis:folder`. If not, either the repository doesn't support it or you don't have the permissions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

But...if create type button is not enable... this repository is not "CMIS standar" ¿no?

Finally, the problem I solved it...very simple... I change

```
$properties = array(
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::OBJECT_TYPE_ID => 'cmis:folder',
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::NAME => 'Demo Folder'
);

try {
    $folder = $session->createFolder(
        $properties,
        $session->createObjectId($session->getRepositoryInfo()->getRootFolderId())
    );
```

By this...

```
$properties = array(
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::OBJECT_TYPE_ID => 'F:oto:Historia',
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::NAME => 'Demo Folder'
);

try {
    $folder = $session->createFolder(
        $properties,
        $session->createObjectId($session->getRepositoryInfo()->getRootFolderId())
    );
```

Where oto it's a model and Historia it's a custom type that I create with Alfresco Console Admin. I included all parent (cm:folder) properties in oto:Historia and create same custom properties.

When I create the folder, it's create with oto:Historia type.